# How do I fix my code for Python Mad lips loops?

Tags: python

I'm having some problems with my code, I have included the prompt and my code below.

Mad Libs are activities that have a person provide various words, which are then used to complete a short story in unexpected (and hopefully funny) ways.

Write a program that takes a string and an integer as input, and outputs a sentence using the input values as shown in the example below. The program repeats until the input string is quit and disregards the integer input that follows.

Ex: If the input is:

apples 5
shoes 2
quit 0
the output is:

Eating 5 apples a day keeps the doctor away.
Eating 2 shoes a day keeps the doctor away.

My code:

```py
word = ''

tokens = ''

while True:

    print('Eating {} {} a day keeps the doctor away.'.format(tokens[0],tokens[1]))

    word = input()
    tokens = input().split()
    if tokens == 'quit':
        break
```

Comment: what's the problem exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while True:
    tokens = input().split()
    if tokens == ['quit']:
        break

    print('Eating {} {} a day keeps the doctor away.'.format(tokens[0],tokens[1]))
```

Comment: the program i use to turn in my codes also adds 0 at the end of quit, causeing the loop to continue. is there a way to stop it from continuing?

Answer (score 0):

According to your problem statement, you have to take the input over and over again until the input string is `quit`.

Try the following piece of code:

```py
while True:
    word = input()
    token = int(input())
    if word == 'quit':
        break
    else:
        print(f'Eating {token} {word} a day keeps the doctor away.')
```

Comment: The code works but continues to give the following error:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\lab\practice.py", line 8, in <module>
    token = int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'quit'

Comment: Try `token=input()` in the third line of the above code and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure i understand but maybe this is what you are looking for.

```
while True:
    word = str(input('Enter word: '))
    tokens = int(input('Enter number: '))
    print('Eating {} {} a day keeps the doctor away.'.format(tokens,word))
    if word == 'quit':
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
tokens = input().split()
index = 0

while True:
    print('Eating {} {} a day keeps the doctor away.'.format(tokens[index + 1],tokens[index]))

    if tokens[index + 2] == 'quit':
        break

    index += 2
```

while this will do what you want. if you input "apples 5 shoes 2 quit 0" it will return

```
Eating 5 apples a day keeps the doctor away.
Eating 2 shoes a day keeps the doctor away.
```

I feel a better way which would be safer is to just stop after you reach the end of tokens which would look something like this:

```
tokens = input().split()
index = 0
maxIndex = len(tokens)

while index + 1 < maxIndex:
    print('Eating {} {} a day keeps the doctor away.'.format(tokens[index + 1],tokens[index]))

    index += 2
```

that way you don't need to add quit and your code won't run forever if you forget it.